# Stock repurchase calculation

Tags: stocks, share-repurchase

I am reading Apple's 10k and trying to understand it. It says they spend $168.6 billion on repurchase but when I add up I get only 18. Am I reading the table wrong?

I multiplied the number of shares by the average price per share:

```
67,990 * 1000 * 94.68  =  $6,437,293,200
40,004 * 1000 * 115.99 =  $4,640,063,960
60,725 * 1000 * 114.00 =  $6,922,650,000
```

Total = $18,000,007,160

I am getting 18 billion instead of 168 billion

[[image]

Comment: "number of shares, which are reflected in thousands" - The number of shares purchased in the first row is 67,990,000. Did you calculate based on that?

Comment: yes, 18000007.16 is also in thousands. So it is 18,000,007,000.16 and not 168 billion....

Answer (score 2):

The activity reported is just for the 3 months ending Sep. 26, 2020. The repurchases have been happening for several quarters that *total* $168B, $18B of which happened in that quarter.

If you look at the previous quarterly reports, you'll see the cumulative total increase from the prior quarter by that quarter's activity. Why the annual report only shows the activity for the past quarter, I can't say.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure that answer works though, if the repurchase plan was announced in April 2020, and the repurchase numbers were as of Sept 2020

Comment: I'm not certain what "April 2020" is referring to, but looking at the prior 10Q, the total repurchased was $150B. That plus the $18B you correctly calculate gives you the $168B.  I suspect that the authorized repurchase was _increased_ in April 2020 since previous 10Qs reference a lower total allowance